# Is There An HTML Function To Execute href?

Tags: html, login-script

I have an HTML log-on script that when it is executed it opens a webpage and logs me in.  It works, but after the log-on page, there's another webpage that opens that I need to click a link on to gain entry to the site

I have tried to add an additional body to my HTML script that is based on an autoClick function to click on the href on the next screen, but it doesn't work.

this code works and logs me in:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>MSP_P2_LogIn</title>
  <script>
    function loginForm() {            
    document.mainform.submit();
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="loginForm()">
    <form action="https://tnt.fnfismd.com/" name="Login" id="mainform" 
    method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user" title="username" id="username" 
     value="MYUSERNAME">
    <input type="password" name="password" title="passwordtext" 
     id="passwordText" value="MYPASSWORD">
    <input type="submit" class="loginBtn" value="LOG IN">
</body>
</html>
```

this is my attempt to click the link on the second page:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>MSP_P2_LogIn</title>
<script>
    function loginForm() {            
    document.mainform.submit();
    }

    function autoClick(){
    document.getElementById('form1').click();
    }

</script>
</head>
 <body onload="loginForm()">
<form action="https://tnt.fnfismd.com/" name="mainform" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user" title="username" id="username" 
    value="MYUSERNAME">
    <input type="password" name="password" title="passwordtext" 
    id="passwordText" value="MYPASSWORD">
    <input type="submit" class="loginBtn" value="LOG IN">
 </body>

 <body onload="setTimeout('autoClick();',3000);">
<a class="Dialog" form="form1" nowrap="" href="RegionChoice.aspx? 
    RegNm=CICSA2&amp;RPCAlias=JAXPLEX1.CICSA2&amp;RegDesc=P2 Test">P2 
    Test</a>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Below is the source code from (https://tnt.fnfismd.com/iportal25/RegionChoice.aspx).  The href is contained in a form, but I don't know how to either submit the form to press the correct link or if I can click the link without submitting another form?

```
<td class="Dialog" nowrap=""><a href="RegionChoice.aspx? 
RegNm=CICSA2&amp;RPCAlias=JAXPLEX1.CICSA2&amp;RegDesc=P2 Test">P2 Test</a> 
</td>
<form name="Form1" id="Form1" action="./RegionChoice.aspx" method="post">

<input name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE"type="hidden"value="lboWwIT5IuhiPyClVYu+Sfk5Vxu3pE5R6gD6w61JEcc6BFJgYJF2HGxpEwJ6gHyCTEznH6N2 Mgr992qdhWYLFPBybb1QfCnI1vm9ZlY6pv0=">

<input name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" type="hidden" 
value="CE974B8E">

<input name="__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED" id="__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED" type="hidden" 
value="">
```

I expect to be able to log into this site (https://tnt.fnfismd.com/), which works with the first HTML script.  Then after I'm logged in, this page automatically displays (https://tnt.fnfismd.com/iportal25/RegionChoice.aspx) and I need to click the href. I'm new to this and I'm stuck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working.  Anyone who needs to log into MSP can use the below HTML script:

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>MSP_Prod_LogIn</title>
    <script>        
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function loginForm(){
        document.mainform.submit();
        window.setTimeout('window.location="https://eportal.fnfismd.com/","";',1000);       
        window.close("eportal.fnfismd.com","");
        window.open("https://eportal.fnfismd.com/","");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="loginForm()">
<form action="https://eportal.fnfismd.com/" name="Login" id="mainform" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user" title="username" id="username" value="[Enter 
     Username Here]">
    <input type="password" name="password" title="passwordtext" id="passwordText" 
    value="[Enter Password Here]"> <input type="submit" class="loginBtn" value="LOG 
    IN">        
</body>
</html>
```

Then execute in C++ like this:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"iexplore.exe", 
    @"C:\HTML_Log_On_Scripts\MSP_Prod_Login.html");
}
```

Works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Wait until the DOM is loaded until you fire functions against it.

```
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
  });
```

Comment: this still doesn't work.  i added the EventListener, but it's still not working.  I am able to log in, but after log in there's a region choice with two links for PROD or P2 Test.  I need to click an href on a different page from the log-in screen